# Supply voltage range for the OP07 op-amp

Tags: power-supply, voltage, operational-amplifier

[OP07 op-amp datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/OP07.pdf)

When it says "Supply Voltage Range +-18V," can I supply it 0 to 36V if I want only single ended operation, or am I limited to 0 to 18V only?

Whatever is your answer, is it applicable to all op-amps?

Comment: Whatever the answer, no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two circuits here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4tlEW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I guarantee you that the voltages at the inputs and output of both opamps is the same except for an 18 V DC offset. The left circuit will have no DC offset, the right circuit has a DC offset. So if opamp in the left circuit outputs 0 V then the opamp in the right circuit outputs 18 V.

From the opamp's point of view, is there a difference?

Can the opamp "know" in which circuit it is used?

Yes or No?

The correct answer is of course No, the opamp cannot tell the difference. The voltages on its pins are the same so from the opamp's point of view, there can be no difference.

In the end, the difference between a +/- 18 V supply or a single 36 V supply is only the **ground reference**.

Comment: Understood well. Thank you so much! :)