# Voltage range of LT6228

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

Can the [LT6228](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc6228-6229.pdf) operate when I supply it with 5 V to 15 V?

I looked around at different articles and posts ([link](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/thesignal/posts/op-amp-voltage-ranges-input-and-output-clearing-some-confusion) & [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595420/supply-voltage-range-for-the-op07-op-amp)) and understood that this should be possible, however, when I tried to prototype it, the negative supply tended to creep upward, drawing more current from my PSU. The phenomenon didn't happen when I changed the supply to ±5 V.

This is my test circuit and the simulation results looks good too:

[image]

What have I missed? Could it be the protection?

====== Update ======

As per user253751 answer, I experimented with a voltage buffer at the op amp's negative power supply and was able to get it to work as a non-inverting amplifier (See my updated simulation). Note that this is different from my original simulation.

[image: Sim circuit]

My captured output on my oscilloscope. There are some "cross-talk" which I will sort out eventually. For now, the buffered negative supply approach appears to work. If anyone has a better solution, please let me know. Happy to learn more.
[image: Yellow = Fn gen input. Green = Negative supply, Blue = Vout and Red = Positive supply]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. The op-amp has no idea what point you are calling 0V. I can take some +5V/-5V circuit, attach one wire to a truck battery, put a sticky note on the other side of the battery that says 0V, and now it's suddenly a +29V/+19V circuit even though nothing actually changed about the circuit and the extra battery isn't doing anything.

However, current flows *out* of the op-amp to its negative supply. So your +5V supply has to be able to *input* current when the voltage tries to go higher than +5V, to keep the voltage down at +5V. Many types of power supplies are only designed to let current go *out* of the power supply.

Comment: This might be the reason. Do you have any recommendation for a voltage regulator circuit that could provide +5V and "sink" current if needed?
Or perhaps another opamp buffer to power this opamp?

Comment: @kenearl note that if this regulator is going to *only* sink current, then it's more like a voltage reference and less like a power supply. I don't have any ideas OTOH but Zener diodes are often used to provide voltage references, they can be buffered with transistor circuits if needed, and you'll probably need a dummy load to pass some current through ti all the time as the op-amp won't always emit enough current to keep the voltage stable

Comment: I will experiment and update my post. Hopefully, the op-amp approach will work.

Comment: After my experiment, I got it to work with a voltage buffer at the negative supply.

Answer (score 1):

> *Can the LT6228 operate when I supply it with 5 V to 15 V?*

The data sheet is quite clear about the maximum voltage supply: -

[image]

- The maximum bipolar supply is +/- 6 volts
- The maximum unipolar supply is 12 volts

> *The phenomenon didn't happen when I changed the supply to ±5 V.*

That doesn't surprise me because that's within the maximum rating.

Comment: V-=+5V and V+=+15V is in-spec.

Comment: @andy-aka when I read the following TI blog, I thought it is possible to shift the voltage supplies as long as they are within spec. In my case, +5V to +15V is 10V. 

Do you think it is not possible to shift the Opamp voltage supply in this manner? 

https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/thesignal/posts/op-amp-voltage-ranges-input-and-output-clearing-some-confusion

Comment: Yes you can offset everything by an arbitrary voltage.